# Doing something if a user reacts to a message Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to make an interactive game with a bot. If you haven't heard of it, it is called high low. A random number 0-100 is chosen. Another random number is chosen. You are shown the second. You have to guess if the first number is higher, lower, or equal to the second. I want to make three reactions. One is an up arrow, one is down, one is an equal sign. How can I execute 3 unique functions when this happens?

(note that the bot will post a message that needs to have a reaction on it. The bot will react with the three emojis first, so these can not accidentally run the code. Thank you.)

Comment: For many it would be helpful to post some details about what you have already learned, tried, and how it failed to produce your expected result. The best questions also contain some code because that can give a ton of context. Guide: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, I would implement a new Reaction event listener. In that reaction event listener I would check to see if the id of the reactor was equal to the id of the bot. If it was, do nothing. Else loop through reaction functions and execute the proper function

Comment: Okay! What is the function that does this? is it on 'react' or something? Sorry, I'm a novice at Discord.js.

Comment: No worries. I would highly recommend taking a look at the discordjs guide. Its really great and helps you understand more about what discordjs actually provides for you https://discordjs.guide/#before-you-begin
The function that does this is client.on(discord.jsEvent, callbackfunction). The best way to set up this structure is in the index which is what they do in that guide. Check out the section on handling events in particular